# Which is a more legitimate recursive helper method?

Tags: java, methods, recursion, helper

My assignment is to write methods for a class where I test for palindromes that a user enters. The class must have a recursive method and that method must call a helper method that removes spaces, punctuation, and ignores case.

I have two working classes that do these things but I'm wondering which structure works better and which helper method actually fits the description of a helper method.

Here's the first class:

```
public class RecursivePalindrome
{

public boolean Palindrome(String s)
{
    return PalindromeHelper(s);
}

public boolean PalindromeHelper(String s)
{
    String a = s.toLowerCase();    //Converts any capital letters to lowercase beforte analyzing the string
    a = a.replaceAll(" ", "");    //Removes any and all spaces in the string

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)     //Removes punctuation by using isLetter method from Character Class
    {
        if(Character.isLetter(a.charAt(i)) == false)
            a = a.replace(a.substring(i, i+1), "");
    }

    if(a.length() == 0 || a.length() == 1)
        return true;
    else if(a.charAt(0) == (a.charAt(a.length() - 1)))
        return PalindromeHelper(a.substring(1, a.length() - 1));
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

And the second one:

```
public class Recurs
{

public boolean Palindrome(String s)
{
    String l = PalindromeHelper(s);

    if(l.length() == 0 || l.length() == 1)
        return true;
    else if(l.charAt(0) == (l.charAt(l.length() - 1)))
        return Palindrome(l.substring(1, l.length() - 1));
    else
        return false;
}

public String PalindromeHelper(String s)
{
    s = s.toLowerCase();    //Converts any capital letters to lowercase before analyzing the string
    s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");    //Removes any and all spaces in the string

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)     //Removes punctuation by using isLetter method from Character Class
    {
        if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) == false)
            s = s.replace(s.substring(i, i+1), "");
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

Comment: The second impl. suits "a helper method that removes spaces, punctuation, and ignores case" obviously

Comment: Is there any way to make the second one more efficient? Everytime Palindrome recurs, it calls the helper method which is unnecessary after the first time the helper is called.

Comment: Then just pull everything below the PalindromHelper() call into a new method (e.g. PalindromRecurse()) and recursively call that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it this way.

```
class RecursivePalindrome
{

    public boolean Palindrome(String s)
    {
        //Think about using a stringbuilder instead of a string.

        String a = s.toLowerCase(); // Converts any capital letters to lowercase
                                    // beforte analyzing the string
        a = a.replaceAll(" ", ""); // Removes any and all spaces in the string

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) // Removes punctuation by using
                                             // isLetter method from Character
                                             // Class
        {
            if (Character.isLetter(a.charAt(i)) == false)
                a = a.replace(a.substring(i, i + 1), "");
        }
        return validatePalindrome(a);
    }

    public boolean validatePalindrome(String s)
    {
        if (s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
            return true;
        else if (s.charAt(0) == (s.charAt(s.length() - 1)))
            return PalindromeHelper(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things before we get to the code...

A "helper" method is more usually called a *utility* method, which is a *stateless* piece of code - being stateless:

- it should be declared as `static`

Adhering to java naming conventions is a great idea, so:

- method names start with a lowercase letter
- boolean methods start with `is` if reasonable to do so

So, your "helper" method should look like this:

```
private static String clean(String s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
}
```

This method does everything your method does, but in a fraction of the code.

Because your main method is also stateless, it too should be static, unless it is required to be an instance method because of class hierarchy or interfaces etc.

Thus, your main method should be:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
     return isPalindromeClean(clean(s));
}

private static boolean isPalindromeClean(String s) {
    return s.length() < 2 || a.endsWith(s.charAt(0)) && 
        isPalindromeClean(l.substring(1, l.length() - 1));
}
```

Again, one line of code does it all. Some things to note:

- your code calls the "clean" method *every* recursion, but by creating a second method, I avoid this inefficiency.
- the use of `endsWith()` to both simply and clarify the condition
- the use of a single simple return statement that encapsulates the logic

The whole class becomes the following, with just 3 lines of actual code.

```
public class Recurse {

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
         return isPalindromeClean(clean(s));
    }

    private static boolean isPalindromeClean(String s) {
        return s.length() < 2 || a.endsWith(s.charAt(0)) && 
          isPalindromeClean(l.substring(1, l.length() - 1));
    }

    private static String clean(String s) {
        return s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
    }
}
```

I wouldn't bother even having the clean method - I would simply in-line it like this:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    return isPalindromeClean(s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", ""));
}
```

But if you've been set an assignment that says you have to create it then you're stuck with it. I would show this alternative though.

Usually, the more elegant the code, the less there is of it.